# Display dynamic columns in a matrix

Tags: reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

[image]

I have a query that returns a static column (checknumber) and dynamic columns and their values (carcass id, kill date, etc.).  I don't know how many columns there will be or their names until runtime.

I'm trying to display this table in a report using a matrix. I can add the checknumber to the row in the designer but am unsure of what to do for the dynamic columns and values.

I think I need to somehow iterate over the columns and get the headings and values. What would an expression be to get the dynamic columns and their values for the matrix?

Answer (score 0):

SSRS does not support Datasets with dynamic columns.

I would build a Dataset that includes all the known columns, and a report that shows them all.

If required, I would hide columns based on either user parameters or data being all Null/Nothing.